# Що таке "скаля"?

Tags: переклад, значення-слів, from-english, from-german

Наткнувся на текст написаний І. Франком наткнувся на таке речення:

> Та тільки музика малює все те тонами, котрих **скаля** і різнородність є
>   дуже обмежена, але котрих зате вона вживає як до потреби, поодиноко
>   або меншими чи більшими гармонійними в’язками (акордами), викликаючи
>   тим способом в нашій душі такі ефекти, яких не може викликати говорене
>   слово.

Захотів подивитися значення в СУМі однак там не знайшов нічого, не знайшов я потрібного значення і в [Зведеному словнику маловживаних та застарілих слів](http://litopys.org.ua/rizne/zvslovnyk.htm#S).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Це або пряме запозичення з анґлійського слова [**scale**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scale), або через німецьке [**die Skala**](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Skala) у значенні: 3. (Musik) Tonleiter. Наведу анґлійське тлумачення:

> 2 : a graduated series of **musical tones** ascending or descending in order of pitch according to a specified scheme of their intervals.

довільно перекладаю:

> 2 : серія поступових **музичних тонів**, що спадають чи наростають в порядку кроку відповідно до означеної схеми їх інтервалів.

Це слово часто запозичують як "шкала", але у вашій цитаті воно має значення "діапазону".

У [словничку з творів Івана Франка](https://zbruc.eu/node/26113) це одне з останніх значень:

> скаля    Скаля́:    Ска́ля:
>   рівень, міра, розмір [II]
>
> тут: **діапазон** [28]
>
> тут: *лад* [48]
>
> *шкала*, рівень [12]

Отже Франко каже, що діапазон і різнородність музичних тонів дуже обмежені, але вправні музиканти вміють так скористатися цією обмеженою кількістю тонів, щоб викликати в нашій душі такі ефекти, яких не може викликати говорене слово.